# Why in Declarative Programming variables are not reassigned?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

I've read that a Declarative language is called "stateless". This means that we can imagine that internally every variable is a constant variable, and it never get reassigned ( in contrast with what usually happens in procedural programming).
How can this work?

Comment: Is it clear what you are asking? Can you elaborate a bit on why you think no reassignment might not work?

Comment: In mathematics, we can plot `f(x) = x*x+4` where `x` ranges from `0` to `10`. We call `x` a variable, even if we don't alter its value in the definition of `f(x)`. I think that if you read some tutorial for any functional programming language, you will understand the general idea: functions work as in maths.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't as exotic as it sounds, and you can do it in a procedural language fairly easily.  The basic idea is just that instead of changing a value you just have a function return a new value.  For instance, instead of something like

```
string read()
{
  string s = '';

  while((string c = getchar()) != '\n')
  {
    s += c;
  }

  return s;
}
```

you could write something like

```
string read()
{
  string c = getchar();

  if(c == '\n')
  {
    return '';
  }
  else
  {
    return c + read();
  }
}
```

See how no variable ever gets reassigned here?

There are some subtleties here that I'm not going into, but I just wanted to illustrate that the idea is not that farfetched.